# How to clear float so my formatting in other elements does not break

Tags: html, css

currently I am trying to make a form and have my radio buttons align to the right of their respective titles. However, upon figuring out how to align the items, the text boxes broke their formatting and now display beside my radio buttons. Is there a way to fix this? I heard that clearing the floats is the solution, however, I cannot figure out how to properly do this, as I am a beginner.

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <title>Bathtub Race Signup Sheet</title>
</head>
<body>

<form>
   <p class="event">*Select Event:</p> 
   <div class="radio1">
   <p><input type="radio" id="stock">Stock</p>
   <p><input type="radio" id="modified">Modified</p>
   </div>

       <p>*Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
       </p>
       <p>*First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"></p>
       <p>*Address: <input type="text" name="address" id="address"></p>
       <p>*City: <input type="text" name="city" id="city"></p>

       <p>*Province: <select name="selectprovince" id="selectprovince">Select Province
       <option value="provinces">...</option>
       <option value="provinces">AB</option>
       <option value="provinces">BC</option>
       <option value="provinces">MB</option>
       <option value="provinces">NB</option>
       <option value="provinces">NL</option>
       <option value="provinces">NT</option>
       <option value="provinces">NS</option>
       <option value="provinces">NU</option>
       <option value="provinces">ON</option>
       <option value="provinces">PE</option>
       <option value="provinces">QC</option>
       <option value="provinces">SK</option>
       <option value="provinces">YT</option>
</select></p>

<p>*Postal/Zip Code: <input type="text" name="postal" id="postal"></p>
<p>*Country: <input type="text" name="country" id="country"></p>
<p>*Email: <input type="text" name="country" id="country"></p>

<label for="date">Date of Birth</label>
<input type="date" name="date" id="date">


<p class="gender">*Gender: </p> 
<div class="radio2">
<p><input type="radio">Male</p>
<p><input type="radio">Female</p>
<p><input type="radio">Other</p>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
<p>*Boat Name: <input type="text" name="boat" id="boat"></p>

<p>Comments <textarea name="comments" form="form" id="comments"></textarea></p>
</div>
</form>
     
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

And CSS

```
body{
    background-color: rgb(134, 210, 221)
}

.event{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

.radio1{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

.radio2{
    float: left;
}

.gender{
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after the floated elements

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(134, 210, 221)
}

.event {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

.radio1 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

.radio2 {
  float: left;
}

.gender {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Bathtub Race Signup Sheet</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form>
    <p class="event">*Select Event:</p>
    <div class="radio1">
      <p><input type="radio" id="stock">Stock</p>
      <p><input type="radio" id="modified">Modified</p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <p>*Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
    </p>
    <p>*First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"></p>
    <p>*Address: <input type="text" name="address" id="address"></p>
    <p>*City: <input type="text" name="city" id="city"></p>

    <p>*Province:
      <select name="selectprovince" id="selectprovince">Select Province
        <option value="provinces">...</option>
        <option value="provinces">AB</option>
        <option value="provinces">BC</option>
        <option value="provinces">MB</option>
        <option value="provinces">NB</option>
        <option value="provinces">NL</option>
        <option value="provinces">NT</option>
        <option value="provinces">NS</option>
        <option value="provinces">NU</option>
        <option value="provinces">ON</option>
        <option value="provinces">PE</option>
        <option value="provinces">QC</option>
        <option value="provinces">SK</option>
        <option value="provinces">YT</option>
      </select>
    </p>

    <p>*Postal/Zip Code: <input type="text" name="postal" id="postal"></p>
    <p>*Country: <input type="text" name="country" id="country"></p>
    <p>*Email: <input type="text" name="country" id="country"></p>

    <label for="date">Date of Birth</label>
    <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <p class="gender">*Gender: </p>
    <div class="radio2">
      <p><input type="radio">Male</p>
      <p><input type="radio">Female</p>
      <p><input type="radio">Other</p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <p>*Boat Name: <input type="text" name="boat" id="boat"></p>

      <p>Comments <textarea name="comments" form="form" id="comments"></textarea></p>
    </div>
  </form>



</body>

</html>
```